# Missing ios option in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have a problem troubled me several days and look forward to any help.
  Everything has been installed and updated to latest stable version, including xamarin.ios.10.30. But there is no ios option. I cannot create an ios app.(Also, when creating xamarin.forms application, ios cannot be selected).
  Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Could you share the version information from the Xamarin Studio? Looks like the Xamarin.iOS isn't installed correctly. You can download the installer from store.xamarin.com or reach out hello@xamarin.com

Comment: I just found this thread. I am having same issue with my Xamarin Studio on my Mac. The iOS option is not there/disabled. When I ran the latest installer for Xamarin studio it says iOS is already installed and doesn't allow me to select it to reinstall it. I am hoping the installed setups it up correctly, but if not, then next is to remove Xamarin studio and reinstall it.

Comment: latest stable Xamarin.iOS is version 10.3.1.7. You mentioned having installed 10.30 but I doubt such version exists...

Comment: thanks a lot. I have fixed it though it's a little weird. My mac is not the latest Sierra 10.12. I updated it to 10.12 and it is ok now. Oh, it's the Xcode that matters. My old 10.10 Yosimate cannot support the latest Xcode. And after updated my mac and Xcode. It works finally.

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove Xamarin Studio completely from Mac and reinstall it, and now working again. The first time I tried to reinstall Xamarin Studio the installer thought Xamain.iOS was already installed, so wouldn't reinstall it.

Uninstall guide:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/uninstalling_xamarin/

follow the steps there for uninstalling stuff on mac, and then reinstall Xamarin Studio.

Comment: thanks a lot. I have fixed it though it's a little weird. My mac is not the latest Sierra 10.12. I updated it to 10.12 and it is ok now. Oh, it's the Xcode that matters. My old 10.10 Yosimate cannot support the latest Xcode. And after updated my mac and Xcode. It works finally.